# Redirect all Custom domains to Laravel Index

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, ssl

We have a Laravel application on a Laravel Forge Nginx server that serves sub.app.com sites and custom domains like `mycustomdomain.com`. The `sub.example.com` sites load well using a wildcard. So does the main app admin domain `my.app.com`.

Custom or customer domains added in app are stored as DNS A and AAAA records with name @ so

```
name @ TTL 1 hr Type A Value ip address
```

They however do not load an app 404 nor try to display a page. They instead direct to app backend `my.app.com`. We have no idea yet why. Subs do load Laravel 404s when they are not present.They (custom domains) should try to serve data from the app.

Here is the the Nginx config we have. 
We have a catch-all:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

and a main config file with wildcard server_name and SSL details including Forge included of which only a before exists:

```
#FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/my.app.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name *.app.com;
    root /home/forge/my.app.com/current/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my.app.com/xxxxx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my.app.com/xxxx/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/my.app.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/my.app.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/my.app.com/after/*;
```

and the before script loads:

```
# Redirect every request to HTTPS...
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name *.app.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Redirect SSL to primary domain SSL...
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my.app.com/xxxxx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my.app.com/xxxxx/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    server_name www.my.app.com;
    return 301 https://my.app.com$request_uri;
}
```

Now custom domain is redirected to 443 and then to my.app.com. It should load root app data.. Any ideas why custom domains do not try to load data like the subdomains and redirect to my.app.com instead?

Comment: Where is your `server` block to handle these custom domains?

Comment: Well I was using the catch-all for that.. Or so I thought. Perhaps I need another block. Been reading more on `$host`,`@server_name` and so on but still have not managed to send all a names we create with custom domain names such as `customdomain.com` and connect to our server ip to go there and serve data from Laravel App just as the subdomains are doing now. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The catch all does not use a web root though and Laravel setups often do and have something like https://gist.github.com/dikaio/601ec9b09b5a282db8b78ab89f1ad92b so perhaps I should add another block .. Will do some trials later one day or tomorrow again.

Comment: Well  `_ `cannot be used instead of `*.app.com` in main block. It will cause the my.app.com not to be loaded nor the subdomains. So another server block is needed it seems. What position and what content I am not sure of yet.

Comment: Using `server {
    listen  *:80 default_server;
    listen  *:443 default_server;
    root /home/forge/my.app.com/current/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my.app.com/xxxxxx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my.app.com/xxxxxx/server.key;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
`
above config in main config file I get a little further. Getting a 403 now so server is hit, not `my.app.com`, but app is not hit yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added another block above the main config and made that default instead of catch-all:

```
server {
    listen  *:80 default_server;
    listen  *:443 default_server;
    root /home/forge/my.app.com/current/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my.app.com/xxxxx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my.app.com/xxxxx/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

this now loads app data. catch-all now has

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

We may need to tweak the main config's new custom domain server block to work with LE SSL instead of the main SSL as we use Let's Encrypt for custom domains, but this specific issue is solved.